# Running MySQL from a virtual server with database on the host disk

Tags: mysql, virtual-machine, network-drive

I'm trying to set up MySQL running in a virtual server (CentOS 6), but as disk intensive stuff isn't great on a VM, I intend to store the database on the host (KVM on CentOS 6) server, and connect to it via Samba or NFS, or the like.

The trouble is that MySQL doesn't seem to like the /var/lib/mysql directory being mounted from a network drive, and I'm getting various different errors in the various configurations I've tried.

My end game is to have the DB server on a VM that can be easily moved between hosts, and the data on a redundant (probably clustered) server. In the mean time, the storage area I'm using on the host server is mirrored using DRBD.

Has anyone done something similar, and can suggest a config that works, or an altogether better way of doing it?

Comment: Just an idea: Can't you use symbolic links to accomplish that? I don't see how a program could not like symbolic links as the actual pointing location/mechanics should be hidden from a program's point of view, as the filesystem is handled by the OS.

Comment: If you're going to physically put the DB on the host, why not just run the DB on the host as well?

Comment: In VMWare, you can add a physical disk (hosts's HD) to the virtual machine as a hard drive/partition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a file level protocol is a **really** bad idea. They are designed to do a **very** different job.

For block device level protocols there's 2 choices (DRBD doesn't apply here). AoE or iSCSI. IIRC, AoE is tightly coupled to physical network interfaces which may cause some complications in your setup - hence I'd recommend having a long hard look at iSCSI.

Comment: I found some nice and simple instructions for doing this [here](http://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=CentOS_6&p=iscsi) and it works!